# docker tmpfs with world writable permission

Tags: linux, docker, containers, tmpfs

I am trying to start a container with read only filesystem, but a specific folder (/app) needs to be world writable.

```
# docker create -it --name=test \
     --read-only \
     --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/app,tmpfs-mode=1777 \
     --entrypoint /bin/bash \
     debian:latest
```

On the first container start, this work fine as expected.

```
# docker start test
test
# docker exec -it test bash
root@c6a9a58b7afe:/#
root@c6a9a58b7afe:/# ls -lrt / | grep app
drwxrwxrwt   2 root root   40 Aug 31 10:19 app
```

Then I stopped the container and started it again.
This time, `/app` is no longer world writable.

```
root@c6a9a58b7afe:/# exit
exit
# docker stop test
test
# docker start test
test
# docker exec -it test bash
root@c6a9a58b7afe:/#  ls -lrt / | grep app
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   40 Aug 31 10:20 app
root@c6a9a58b7afe:/#
```

Why is this difference seen on first (`drwxrwxrwt`) and subsequent (`drwxr-xr-x`) container instances?
How to make this permanently world writable?

Comment: If you delete the container and run a new one, is it better?  In most cases you shouldn't need `docker start`.

Comment: @DavidMaze If I use 'docker stop' and 'docker rm' to delete container, and create new with 'docker create' this problem is not seen. I wanted to understand why  this behavior happens with docker stop and start. Apart from this issue, docker stop/start is enough for my other use cases.